# My Node.js app is not detecting the mongoose method findByIdAndDelete as a function

Tags: node.js, mongoose, backend, mongoose-schema

Thanks for taking the time to read this.

I have an schema defined like this,

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');


//modelo de categorias
const categoriaEsquema = mongoose.Schema({
    nombre: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    color: {
        type: String,
    },
    icono: {
        type: String,
    },
    /*imagen: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },*/ //Aún no se usa
})

exports.CategoriaModelo = mongoose.model('Categoria',categoriaEsquema);
```

And I am trying to achieve a DELETE request with the following code in other page

```
const {CategoriaModelo} = require('../modelos/categorias');
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

router.delete('/:id', (req, res) => {
    CategoriaModelo.findByIdAndRemove(req.params.id);
});


module.exports = router;
```

But it throws me this error:

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HTiyR.png)

Please help me, thank you in advance

I tried using other methods like finOneAnd... etc, but it seems like it is not detecting Mongoose methods at all.

Comment: Hi, the use of images for code/errors causes many problems. Please read [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/7353417).  Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [findByIdAndDelete](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/model.html#Model.findByIdAndDelete()) instead and await the asynchronous call like so:

```js
router.delete('/:id', async (req, res) => { //< Mark callback as async
   try{
      const deletedDoc = await CategoriaModelo.findByIdAndDelete(req.params.id);
      return res.status(200).json({
         message: 'Delete was a success'
      })
   }catch(err){
      console.log(err);
      //Handle error
      return res.status(400).json({
         message: 'Error on server'
      });
   }
});
```

**Edit**:

You also need to use the `new` keyword in your schema definition:

```js
const categoriaEsquema = new mongoose.Schema({
   //...
});
```